# avova one way vs multiway

Tags: r, anova

Hello I'm running anova with R and I am wondering what the differce is between multiway anova and single anova. I know single anova gives a different answer than multiway anova but I dont know how to quantify multiway anova.
Could someone explain in words the difference between:

- base~col1
- base~col1+col2
- base~col1*col2

http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/Education/Lectures/R/anova.htm#anova_1

How do I interpret the results of col1+col2 and col1*col2
because col2 is giving a P(>F) of  0.473 on single anova but P(>F) 4.21e-07 in multiway anova. col2 does correlate well with base having only a 2% coloration for 711 individuals. According to http://vassarstats.net/rsig.html 2% coloration isn't significant. 
Thank you

edit:
i know my col1 and col2 have some interactions is that causing the low multiple anova p value?

i am using

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1+col2,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
```

and the results are not simular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, single ANOVA tests between-groups for a single independent variable (`col1`) for a response variable (`base`). Multiway ANOVA tests between-groups for two or more independent variables (`col1` and `col2`). The choice to use one or the other depends on your experimental design.

`base~col1` is testing a single "main" effect

`base~col1+col2` would be testing two "main" effects only

`base~col1*col2` would be testing two "main" effects along with the "interaction" effect between independent variables.

[Some more info about two-way ANOVA](http://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch13-2wy.html)

**Edit:** Given your updated post:

I suspect you made a mistake in the code you gave as example, but here are some explanations:

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1+col2,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
```

This would test for only main effects of col1 and main effects of col2. In other words, are there any differences between groups for col1 or col2?

```
aov.ex2 <- aov(base~col1,data=data1) 
summary(aov.ex2)
```

This would test for only the main effect of col1. In other words, are there any differences between groups for col1?

It seems like your basic problem is that with the inclusion of a second independent variable you are getting different results. [This post may be of relevance.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7620/main-effect-of-the-first-independent-variable-in-two-way-anova-lost-depending-on)

Comment: ok that makes some sense what would you say to col2 not corolating to base but having a low p vaule. what does that mean? i really need to know why this is happening and why there is no p value for it individually but there is a p vale for it coroporately

Comment: @caseyr547 can you give us an example of the code you're using (I'm assuming `aov()` from your previous link) and output? It's unclear what effects you're referring to.

Comment: i updated the question adding some code :)

Comment: the edit you just made is missing information :) I'm excited to see what you have to say

Comment: Should be updated now. Could you give us a better idea of the dataset? How many groups are you comparing between? Is the data parametric?

Comment: i have 711 individuals with two basic groups but the group 1 varies by degrees the data is numerical

Comment: if i understand your answer i can safely ignore the interactions between my col1 and col2 staying with one way anova because the cols corolate

Comment: Well, it sounds like your data/design may not be appropriate for ANOVA. To get this straight, correct me if I'm wrong: you have a single response variable (`base`, numerical, on a continuous scale?), and two independent variables (`col1` and `col2`). What are your "groups"? E.g., what are the different treatments you are interested in comparing?

Comment: i have one single repsonse which isnt continous it it ranges from 0 to n with duplicates i have 53 characteristic variables some of which corrolate together and others which are indepent. i am measuring my ability to predict the base by the characteristics which corrolate to base in degrees

Comment: 53 characteristic variables? These sound like your independent variables (of which some are collinear as you've indicated) while `col1` and `col2` sound like your groups. What you're looking for is probably multiple linear regression modelling, and definitely some rigorous model selection to check for multicollinearity (to remove bias) and find significant predictors (using AIC stepwise selections). Check out [this link](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/regression.html) for some example code in R.

Comment: It looks like this moved into a different question regarding the actual solution to the OPs problem rather than the definition of two-way ANOVA and the interpretation of the R code.  At that point wouldn't it be a good idea for the OP to start a new question and have the subsequent comments be asnwers to that question?  Just my read on how the site is suppose to work (coming from a novice who has only 14 days of experience on the site).

Comment: @MichaelChernick your right I'll start a new question about multiple linear regression :)